# any one tells me resul is not displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, col

```
<?php 

$stmt=DB_uf::prepare('SELECT c_id, c_name   FROM cata_log ORDER BY c_id, c_name') ;
  
     $stmt->execute();
    
  $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_NUM);  
    foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    $catalog = $row[':c_id'];
    $product_name = $row[':c_name'];
    echo $catalog ;
    echo $product_name;
   }
  
//if ($result->num_rows > 0) {}
//$stmt->execute();
?>
```

result finds as

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 19

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 19

how  i get feild valu from kindly help me?
only this program improve

```
<?php 

$stmt=DB_uf::prepare('SELECT c_id, c_name   FROM cata_log ORDER BY c_id, c_name') ;
  
     $stmt->execute();
    
  $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_NUM);  
    foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    $catalog = $row[':c_id'];
    $product_name = $row[':c_name'];
    echo $catalog ;
    echo $product_name;
   }
  
//if ($result->num_rows > 0) {}
//$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 19

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 19

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 19

Warning: Undefined array key ":c_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\menu_selector.php on line 20

Comment: print your array $row and you will see what your array keys are which have your values. You then use those key to show the values

Comment: delete the : in your arrayKeys

Answer (score 0):

delete the : in your arrayKeys

i.e.

```
<?php 

$stmt=DB_uf::prepare('SELECT c_id, c_name   FROM cata_log ORDER BY c_id, c_name') ;
  
     $stmt->execute();
    
  $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_NUM);  
    foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    $catalog = $row['c_id'];
    $product_name = $row['c_name'];
    echo $catalog ;
    echo $product_name;
   }
  
//if ($result->num_rows > 0) {}
//$stmt->execute();
?>
```